# Me da error al comprobar si hay ganador en Conecta4

Tags: java

estaba programando el mítico juego 'Conecta4', en el que gana el primero que consigue poner 4 en raya, apilando por columnas. El juego se basa en un `array[6][6]` y las rayas pueden ser tanto verticales, horizontales y diagonales (ambos sentidos). La cosa es que cuando apilo por ejemplo 3 X's seguidas (una encima de otra), me salta el mensaje `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6 at utils.Tablero.hayGanador(Tablero.java:66) at Conecta4.Conecta4.jugar(Conecta4.java:46) at Conecta4.Conecta4.main(Conecta4.java:57)"` 
Sólo me da problemas con las verticales, no entiendo por qué. Seguro que luego es una tontería.
El código que tengo para comprobar si hay ganador es:

```
public boolean hayGanador() {

    // CON ESTOS DOS FOR RECORREMOS LA ARRAY ENTERA HORIZONTALMENTE //
    int contador;
    for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (tablero[i][j] != VACIO && tablero[i][j] == tablero[i][j+1] && tablero[i][j] == tablero[i][j+2] && tablero[i][j] == tablero[i][j+3]) {
                System.out.println("Horizontal");
                return true;
            }
        }
        contador = 0;
    }

    // ESTE FOR RECORRE EN VERTICAL //
    for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (tablero[j][i] != VACIO && tablero[j][i] == tablero[j+1][i] && tablero[j][i] == tablero[j+2][i] && tablero[j][i] == tablero[j+3][i]) {
                System.out.println("Vertical");
                return true;
            }
        }
        contador = 0;
    }

    // ESTE FOR RECORRE LA ARRAY EN DIAGONAL HACIA ARRIBA
    for(int j = 3; j < tablero.length; j++){
        // AQUI SUMAS LA J (OSEA LAS FILAS)
        for(int l = 0; l < tablero[0].length - 3; l++){
            // AQUI SUMAS LA L (OSEA LAS COLUMNAS)
            // EN ESTE IF COMROBAMOS QUE J Y L SEAN IGUAL A 1 (OSEA "X") EN LOS SIGUENTES AND RESTAMOS LA J Y SUMAMOS LA L HACIENDO ASI UNA DIAGONAL DE TODA LA VIDA //
            if (tablero[j][l] != VACIO && tablero[j][l] == tablero[j-1][l+1] && tablero[j-1][l+1] == tablero[j-2][l+2] && tablero[j-2][l+2] == tablero[j-3][l+3]) {
                System.out.println("Diagonal hacia arriba");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // ESTE FOR RECORRE LA ARRAY EN DIAGONAL HACIA ABAJO
    for(int j = 0; j < tablero.length - 3; j++){
        // AQUI SUMAS LA J (OSEA LAS FILAS)
        for(int l = 0; l < tablero[0].length - 3; l++){
            // AQUI SUMAS LA L (OSEA LAS COLUMNAS)
            // EN ESTE IF COMROBAMOS QUE J Y L SEAN IGUAL A 1 (OSEA "X") EN LOS SIGUENTES AND SUMAMOS LA J Y RESTAMOS LA L HACIENDO ASI UNA DIAGONAL DE TODA LA VIDA PERO HACIA ABAJO //
            if (tablero[j][l] != VACIO && tablero[j][l] == tablero[j+1][l+1] && tablero[j+1][l+1] == tablero[j+2][l+2] && tablero[j+2][l+2] == tablero[j+3][l+3]) {
                System.out.println("Diagonal hacia abajo");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Si a alguien se le ocurriese qué puede estar fallando por favor que me ayude. Muchas gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Comment: `tablero[j+3]` da 6 cuando j es 3 y esa posición no essiste

Answer (score 1):

ten presente que los indices en un `array` parten del indice `0` si es un array de 6 los indices serán `0 1 2 3 4 5`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    if (tablero[j][i] != VACIO && tablero[j][i] == tablero[j+1][i]
 && tablero[j][i] == tablero[j+2][i] && tablero[j][i] == tablero[j+3][i])
```

cuando `j` tome el ultimo valor osea `3` tu le sumas en las condicionales

+1 =`indice 4 existe` luego

+2=`indice 5 existe` y después

+3=`indice 6??` el cual no existe por lo que te arroja esa exception

esto no solo va pasar en el `horizontal` como mencionas también en el `vertical`
por lo que el valor de tu segundo for deber ser menor a 3 de esa manera te aseguras que tu ciclo no desborde tu array.ademas de cumplir correctamente la especificación del conecta4

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
```

Comment: Estaba claro que iba a ser alguna tontería, muchas gracias a los que habéis respondido!!!